# C# DateTime and calculation

Tags: c#, datetime

Basically I am wanting to find how long someone has been 'Active' for.

This is used first when the user starts:

> start_hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
>
> start_min = DateTime.Now.Minute;
>
> start_time = start_hour + ":" + start_minute;

Then after the user has finished (could be an hour or two later or an hour and a half later) they click a button and it records the same thing:

> end_hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
>
> end_min = DateTime.Now.Minute;
>
> end_time = end_hour + ":" + end_minute;

I want to get the amount of hours and minutes they have been active.

Thanks

Comment: So all you need is a link to a tutorial for this, right?

Comment: I have had a look but I don't really understand...

Comment: i bet Jon Skeet will have a field day with the problems of doing this. Summertime, timezones, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
TimeSpan span = (end_time  - start_time );

var totaltime= String.Format("{0} days, {1} hours, {2} minutes, {3} seconds", 
    span.Days, span.Hours, span.Minutes, span.Seconds);
```

Comment: How would I print that out?

Comment: Console.WriteLine(totaltime);

Comment: I have defined start_time and end_time as a string and it says

Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Comment: set var start_time=DateTime.Now when the app starts and set var end_time=DateTime.Now when it ends. I am not sure why are using Battery1StartHour ,Battery1StartMinute though.